# Multiple Callback Design Pattern?

Tags: android, android-async-http

this question is more design related. Am using the Android Async-Http-Client library http://loopj.com/android-async-http/  to make multiple call request from different methods in a class so my code is something like this

```
RestClient.post(context, "", entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
                    // Map objects from json using gson
                }
            });
```

if different methods in my classes making similar calls like the code Above but with different request params, how can i encapsulate the ResponseHandler Callback so i don't have to keep repeating it in every method call.  Was wondering if there is any other nice design pattern method i can use here.

**Note**

i have thought of subclassing it and as others have suggested, but i can't seem to get the json object response that way.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is the callback behavior identical across all of these requests? If so, you could either create a single shared instance of JsonHttpResponseHandler and use that everywhere:

```
private JsonHttpResponseHandler handler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(...) {
        ...
    }
}

...

RestClient.post(..., handler);
```

or you could create a subclass of JsonHttpResponseHandler and use that:

```
public class MyResponseHandler extends JsonHttpResponseHandler {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(...) {
        ...
    }
}

...

RestClient.post(..., new MyResponseHandler());
```

Comment: yeah i could have done that but i forgot to add this. My problem is  for some reason, i can't get the returned Json response that way.

Answer (score 0):

You dont have to create a new handler for every call.

```
JsonHttpResponseHandler myHandler = new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
                // Map objects from json using gson
            }
        };

RestClient.post( context, "", entity, "application/json", myHandler );
```

Comment: thanks for the response, i know, but since it is asynchronous, how do you know which call is which if the methods can be called at once?

Answer (score 0):

How about extracting it as a method:

```
private void restClients(RestClient restClient){
    restClient.post(context, "", entity, "application/json", new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONObject response) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, JSONArray timeline) {
            // Map objects from json using gson
        }
    });
}
```

Then simply calling the method:

```
restClients(restclient1)
```